# Fetch within one to many relationship in MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord, and I have a one-to-many relationship.
Say Department have many employees. 
What's the syntax for finding a specific employee within a specific Department, given a property. (fetch with more than one attribute, but one of them was a one-to-many relationship).

For performance purpose, I would like to avoid retrieving a Set of Employees from a Department, and search that array through a for loop manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Employee has an 'employeeID' and an inverse to-one relationship of department
and Department has a to-many relationship to Employees as employees

you should off the top of my head be able to do something like:

```
Department * dept = [self getDepartmentManagedObjectFromCD];
NSString * employeeID = @"52";

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employeeID == %@ && department == %@", employeeID, dept];
```

You can actually pass the department object in as a search parameter - I dont use MagicalRecord much but you want one of the MR_findBy that takes an NSPredicate

Comment: Actually, I tested it again, although the code execute, it reported valueForUndefinedKey: the entity Department is not key value coding-compliant for the key "department".

Comment: Solved, I used the wrong name, it should be departmentrelationship... Thank you